# javascript for draw rectangle over a image

Tags: javascript, image

I was doing a project on php  with java script.I was try to draw a rectangle over a image using javascript.The rectangle can draw any where of the image with any size as compare with image size and also display the co ordinate of drawing rectangle.Please any one help me...I was tried different ways.....

```
 <STYLE>
  #rubberBand {
  position: absolute;
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 0px; height: 0px;
  border: 2px solid red;
 }
 </STYLE>

 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <img name="myImage" id="myImage" src="a.jpg">


 <DIV ID="rubberBand"></DIV>

 <SCRIPT>

var IMG;

  function startRubber (evt) {
   if (document.all) {

       var r = document.all.rubberBand;
       r.style.width = 0;
       r.style.height = 0;
       r.style.pixelLeft = event.x;
      r.style.pixelTop = event.y;
      r.style.visibility = 'visible';
      IMG.ondragstart = cancelDragDrop; // otherwise IE will try to drag the image
   }
     else if (document.getElementById) {
   // firefox
   evt.preventDefault();
    var r = document.getElementById('rubberBand');
   r.style.width = 0;
  r.style.height = 0;
   r.style.left = evt.clientX + 'px';
    r.style.top = evt.clientY + 'px';
   r.style.visibility = 'visible';
   r.onmouseup = stopRubber;
    }
    IMG.onmousemove = moveRubber;
   }
   function moveRubber (evt) {
   if (document.all) { // IE
   var r = document.all.rubberBand;
    r.style.width = event.x - r.style.pixelLeft;
  r.style.height = event.y - r.style.pixelTop;
   }
   else if (document.getElementById) { // firefox
   var r = document.getElementById('rubberBand');
   r.style.width = evt.clientX - parseInt(r.style.left);
    r.style.height = evt.clientY - parseInt(r.style.top);
   }
   return false; // otherwise IE won't fire mouseup :/
   }
  function stopRubber (evt) {
  IMG.onmousemove = null;
   }

  function cancelDragDrop()
   {
  window.event.returnValue = false;
   }

   IMG = document.getElementById('myImage');
   IMG.onmousedown = startRubber;
   IMG.onmouseup = stopRubber;

 </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: What ways have you tried? A resizing image? Canvas? Flash?

Comment: Show what you've attempted, and we'll try to help fix it. But we're not going to write code for you.

Comment: What are these different ways you tried? How are you loading the image? Is this client-side JavaScript? Do you need to have full cross-browser compatibility?

Answer (score 8):

You need a wrapper so you can absolutely-position elements inside. The dimensions will vary, depending on your photo and where you want the box.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <img src="...." />
     <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

.box {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:2px solid #ffffff;
    background-color:transparent
}
```